# What is the difference between ‘by myself’ and ‘myself’?

Tags: word-usage, reflexive-pronouns

> 1. I would like to look for it myself.
> 2. I would like to look for it by myself.

What is the difference between the two sentences above?

Comment: In some contexts including ***by*** wouldn't affect the meaning. In others, plain ***myself*** might be simply ***emphatic*** (although other people might have seen it, I won't believe it until I've seen it ***with my own eyes***). Including ***by*** would normally imply *I want to look at it **in private*** (with nobody else around at the time).

Comment: Thus *John did it himself* implies that although you might have expected someone else to do it, ***it was actually John*** who did it. But *John did it **by** himself* implies ***John did it alone*** (usually, ***without anyone else helping***; sometimes ***with no-one else around***).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between myself and by myself](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/55064/difference-between-myself-and-by-myself)

Answer (score 4):

Doing something "myself" indicated that I am the one doing it, in contrast with having someone else do it. "I know you said you couldn't find it, but I would like to look for it myself."

On the other hand, doing something "[by myself](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/by+myself)" emphasizes that I am doing it alone, which can mean that no one is assisting me ("Please don't help. I would like to look for it by myself.") or that no other people are present ("Please leave the room. I would like to look for it by myself.").