# "Playing games (by myself / myself / alone)" - Grammar and nuance?

Tags: sentence-construction

Q1. Here, I think all of them are right to use, but I want to know if there's any difference in nuance.

> Playing computer games (by myself / myself / alone) can be fun for a certain amount of time, but it usually becomes boring.

Q2. I'd like to know if ***'The fact'*** can be used as a subject here, and I know I can use ***'alone'*** here, but I want to know if the others are possible to mean the same thing. And which one makes the most sense: after that / after a while / at some point?

> ***The fact*** that I have a girl friend can be great for a certain amount of time, but (after that / after a while / at some point) I start to think I wish I was (alone / by myself / myself).

Comment: The second part "The fact..." is not related and should be a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

These two are similar:

> Playing computer games **alone** can be fun ...

*alone* implies you are playing by yourself, and maybe there is nobody else around.

> Playing computer games **by myself** can be fun ...

*by myself* implies only that you are the only person playing computer games. There could be other people around doing other things.

> Playing computer games **myself** can be fun ...

In this arrangement, *myself* simply refers to you regarding the phrase containing it. You could substitute "for me" in its place. For example:

> Playing computer games **myself/for me** can be fun, but my girlfriend would rather go shopping.

Comment: There is also an interpretation like this: *playing computer games myself can be fun but I generally prefer to pay someone to play them for me;  I get much higher scores that way.*