# 'Alone', 'on one's own' and 'by oneself'

Tags: meaning

I was wondering if the following sentence mean the same:

> **1.** I like to be **alone** most of the time. 
>   **2.** I like to be **on my own** most of the time. 
>   **3.** I like to be **by myself** most of the time.

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/29398/230

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/7335/230

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. They all refer to not being with anybody else, so you can use them interchangeably in the sentence you've given.